# How can I change the icon of a single file on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons

I am running mac, and made a file, transferred it to my Windows 7 computer, and the icon isn't there. I took my icon file, and tried to change it, but I could not figure out how. I want it so that I can change the files icon, but only that files icon, not every file of that type. I also want it so that when others download it, they see the icon too. Two things I must say though: I want instructions, not a link. Also, I want the simplest, that follows all of my requirements. Please help me, thanks.

P.S. If it helps, it is a .gba file.

Answer (score 1):

Its the way Windows 7 changes the icons:

Executable Win32 icons [*.exe] > you can have any icon you want for each file

other formats are depends on which application is associated with or which icon file you set on your own PC

GBA files are not Win32 executable, so this is my suggested solution (needs WinRaR application):

1. install WinRaR
2. right click on your file and select "Add to archive ..."
3. set "Compression method" to "store"
4. in "Archiving options" group check "Create SFX archive"
5. go to "Advanced" tab and click on "SFX options ..." button
6. in "text and icon" tab select "browse ..." button of "Load SFX icon from a file" part and select your icon. (for now you will have an installer for your file with your icon. but if you don't want to install it (and see a progress bar) go to 7, if you want to make an installer go to 8.)
7. go to "Modes" tab and select "Hide all" in "silent Mode" group
8. press OK for all opened windows and wait for your archive to be created.

done. now you archived your file into an EXE file with your icon on it. to use it you have to extract it by double clicking on it, and the GBA file will appear next to EXE file.